# 'tblPerson' table - Unable to add constraint 'CK_tblPerson_age'

Tags: sql, constraints, ssms

Iam very new to this Sql. Started learning recently, Being a accounts graduate, little slow in learning and understanding.

This is the error iam getting.

> 'tblPerson' table - Unable to add constraint 'CK_tblPerson_age'.   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK_tblPerson_age". The conflict occurred in database "sample", table "dbo.tblPerson", column 'Age'.

Attached pics below how my ssms screen looks.

[image]

[image]

Please help.

Thanks a ton in advance,
Cheers

Comment: your constraint says that age should be greater than 0, however you already got a value in your table with an age less than 0 - which violates your constraint.

Comment: Please show the code that you are running.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As the for error, it's telling you the problem. There is at least 1 row that would cause the `CONSTRAINT` to fail, so it cannot be added. Personally, however, I recommend against storing age; store a Date of Birth then you can work out the age. Someone who inputs their age as "35" today, may well not be 35 tomorrow.

Comment: @wosi Thank you a ton, I got the answer.

Comment: *How* does someone have an age of -10? This is another reason why storing the date of birth is a good idea.

Comment: Iam practising, just doing some trial and error :)